# How to perform numeric division in a hash of hashes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this data relative to students participation hour-by-hour in the gym classes.

I need to normalize this data in scale of 0 and 1.
So I'm trying to divide distribution_by_place by total_distribution

Is there a nice way to perform this operation?

Sample of distribution_by_place

```
{["cardio", "00"]=>0,
 ["cardio", "01"]=>0,
 ["cardio", "02"]=>0,
 ["cardio", "03"]=>0,
 ["cardio", "04"]=>0,
 ["cardio", "05"]=>0,
 ["cardio", "06"]=>0,
 ["cardio", "07"]=>0,
 ["cardio", "08"]=>0,
 ["cardio", "09"]=>0,
 ["cardio", "10"]=>0,
 ["cardio", "11"]=>0.35e2,
 ["cardio", "12"]=>0,
 ["cardio", "13"]=>0,
 ["cardio", "14"]=>0,
 ["cardio", "15"]=>0,
 ["cardio", "16"]=>0,
 ["cardio", "17"]=>0,
 ["cardio", "18"]=>0,
 ["cardio", "19"]=>0,
 ["cardio", "20"]=>0,
 ["cardio", "21"]=>0,
 ["cardio", "22"]=>0,
 ["cardio", "23"]=>0,
 ["swimming", "00"]=>0,
 ["swimming", "01"]=>0,
 ["swimming", "02"]=>0,
 ["swimming", "03"]=>0,
 ["swimming", "04"]=>0,
 ["swimming", "05"]=>0,
 ["swimming", "06"]=>0,
 ["swimming", "07"]=>0,
 ["swimming", "08"]=>0,
 ["swimming", "09"]=>0,
 ["swimming", "10"]=>0,
 ["swimming", "11"]=>0.35e2,
 ["swimming", "12"]=>0,
 ["swimming", "13"]=>0.3e2,
 ["swimming", "14"]=>0,
 ["swimming", "15"]=>0,
 ["swimming", "16"]=>0,
 ["swimming", "17"]=>0,
 ["swimming", "18"]=>0,
 ["swimming", "19"]=>0,
 ["swimming", "20"]=>0,
 ["swimming", "21"]=>0,
 ["swimming", "22"]=>0,
 ["swimming", "23"]=>0}
```

Sample of total_distribution

```
{"00"=>0,
 "01"=>0,
 "02"=>0,
 "03"=>0,
 "04"=>0,
 "05"=>0,
 "06"=>0,
 "07"=>0,
 "08"=>0,
 "09"=>0,
 "10"=>0,
 "11"=>0.7e2,
 "12"=>0,
 "13"=>0.3e2,
 "14"=>0,
 "15"=>0,
 "16"=>0,
 "17"=>0,
 "18"=>0,
 "19"=>0,
 "20"=>0,
 "21"=>0,
 "22"=>0,
 "23"=>0}
```

expected result

```
{["cardio", "00"]=>0,
 ["cardio", "01"]=>0,
 ["cardio", "02"]=>0,
 ["cardio", "03"]=>0,
 ["cardio", "04"]=>0,
 ["cardio", "05"]=>0,
 ["cardio", "06"]=>0,
 ["cardio", "07"]=>0,
 ["cardio", "08"]=>0,
 ["cardio", "09"]=>0,
 ["cardio", "10"]=>0,
 ["cardio", "11"]=>0.5,
 ["cardio", "12"]=>0,
 ["cardio", "13"]=>0,
 ["cardio", "14"]=>0,
 ["cardio", "15"]=>0,
 ["cardio", "16"]=>0,
 ["cardio", "17"]=>0,
 ["cardio", "18"]=>0,
 ["cardio", "19"]=>0,
 ["cardio", "20"]=>0,
 ["cardio", "21"]=>0,
 ["cardio", "22"]=>0,
 ["cardio", "23"]=>0,
 ["swimming", "00"]=>0,
 ["swimming", "01"]=>0,
 ["swimming", "02"]=>0,
 ["swimming", "03"]=>0,
 ["swimming", "04"]=>0,
 ["swimming", "05"]=>0,
 ["swimming", "06"]=>0,
 ["swimming", "07"]=>0,
 ["swimming", "08"]=>0,
 ["swimming", "09"]=>0,
 ["swimming", "10"]=>0,
 ["swimming", "11"]=>0,
 ["swimming", "12"]=>0,
 ["swimming", "13"]=>1,
 ["swimming", "14"]=>0,
 ["swimming", "15"]=>0,
 ["swimming", "16"]=>0,
 ["swimming", "17"]=>0,
 ["swimming", "18"]=>0,
 ["swimming", "19"]=>0,
 ["swimming", "20"]=>0,
 ["swimming", "21"]=>0,
 ["swimming", "22"]=>0,
 ["swimming", "23"]=>0}
```

These is the functions

```
def hourly_periods
  HourlyPeriod
    .where(location_id: location.id)
    .where("start_at >= ? and end_at <= ?", start_date, end_date)
    .where.not(corrupted: true)
end

def distribution_by_place
  hourly_periods.includes(:place_type)
    .where.not(place_type_id: gym_entrance.id)
    .group("place_types.name")
    .group_by_hour_of_day(:start_at, format: "%H")
    .average(:attendance)
end

def total_distribution
  hourly_periods.includes(:place_type)
    .where.not(place_type_id: gym_entrance.id)
    .group_by_hour_of_day(:start_at, format: "%H")
    .average(:attendance)
end
```

Comment: Your functions will output ActiveRecord::Relations, not hashes.

Comment: In future please reduce the size of your example to the smallest that still makes the point. Also, assign a variable to each input value (e.g., `h = {["cardio", "00"]=>0,...`) so that readers can refer to those variables in answers and comments without having to define them.

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring your functions, and just looking at the example hashes you've shown you could do it like this:

```
distribution_by_place.each do |key, value|
  index = key.second
  distribution_by_place[key] = value / total_distribution[index] unless total_distribution[index] == 0
end
```